# How to install mpfit.py in python

Tags: python

I am regular user of IDL but very new to python. I got `mpfit.py` file but I don't know how to install this file so that I can import it in my code. Please help...

Comment: By `install`, do you mean you want to include the file in your existing Python code?  You can import the mpfit.py file by placing it in the current directory, and calling `import mpfit`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install it necessarily, 
From the directory you have your script you can always import. 
e.g. if your script is in:

```
C:\my scripts\MyCoolScript.py
C:\my scripts\mpfit.py
```

Inside `MyCoolScript.py` you should have:

```
from mpfit import *
```

#### If your `mpfit.py` is somewhere else:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\SomewhereElse")

from mpfit import *
```

#### Note about importing stuff.

In many `__init__.py` of modules you will see this `from somemodule import *`.
This however, is considered an offensive way of importing.

There reason is the following, if you defined a method or a variable or an object with the name `something` and the file `mpfit` has also `something` in it. the moment you import `*` from `mpfit` you will override the local value of `something`. This is also true the other way around. If you do `from mpfit import *` and you where hoping to use, for example `constant=6.13` in your code, but later you defined `constant=128` inside your script, than your `constant` imported from `mpfit` will be overridden.
Hence, Python coders import the whole module or script itself and use the `.` operator to access some property, e.g.:

```
import mpfit
```

now you can access stuff inside mpfit like this:

```
mpfit.superfunction(var1, var2)

mpfit.constanst*something
```

if you are 'lazy' you could also import something with a short name:

```
import mpfit as mt
mt.superfunction(var1, var2)
mt.constanst*something
```

Welcome to Python, a way better choice than IDL.

Comment: don't use wildcard imports (`*`) outside REPL

Comment: Second what @J.F.Sebastian says. There's no reason to use the `from...import *` syntax here: just do `import mpfit` and refer to the functions inside as `mpfit.foo()` etc.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yes, in principle you are right. However, since the OP is a Python newbie, I wanted to spare him confusion.

Comment: Well, IMO the way to introduce newbies to Python is not to give them advice that will serve them badly later, but to tell them how to do things correctly right from the start.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, You have a point there, I still don't think that answer is that bad. But I will add your notes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

sys.path.append("path of your file")
```

Now, your module is included in sys. path, you can simply import it:

```
import mpyfit
```